# How do devtas die and are replaced in every Manvantara if they have amrit

Tags: gods, pralaya

[Amrita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amrita) or Amurta is the divine potion for eternal life which is given to [Devas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deva_%28Hinduism%29). So if the Amruta gives eternal life to the Devtas or Devas in Swargaloka how is Swargaloka annihilated during end of every Manvantara, i.e. Partial Destruction of whole Creation, replacing the Posts like that of Indra, Yama, Agni, Varuna, Vayu etc with new jivas.

Comment: I think Amrita is more about keeping the gods young forever as long as they are alive, not about being impervious to death in battle or to Pralayas.

Comment: Yes,as you know without liberation, Everybody have to die & take birth,it's law. amrita doesn't mean liberation, it's means your life will increase for some specific time.after completing their Good deeds account they again have to take birth.

Comment: @Yogi, do you agree that no physical body can last forever ? Even when asuras do penance and ask Brahma for immortality, he denies it saying it is against natural law of universe. So, drinking Amrita does not mean immortality, it only prolongs life. Like I mentioned in my answer before it got deleted, all Devas have to fall back to earth (i.e their Deva-body dies) after their Punya is exhausted.

Comment: If Amrit only prolongs life and is not granting immortality then Rahu should have died that very moment when his head was chopped by Lord Vishnu's Sudarshan Chakra. But he was alive even when his head and body were not connected. So, I don't think it is only for prolonging life but should be more than that.